# Yahoo PlaceFinder address quality

Tags: yahoo-api

From the [Yahoo! PlaceFinder documentation](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/guide/responses.html#address-quality), here are the values for the address quality (the accuracy of the data):

```
Value   Description
99      Coordinate
90      POI
87      Address match with street match
86      Address mismatch with street match
85      Address match with street mismatch
84      Address mismatch with street mismatch
82      Intersection with street match
80      Intersection with street mismatch
```

My question is with the value `85`. How can the address match while the street doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

This will happen when you miss spell the streetname for example, in my case I 'forgot' a vowel in the streetname.
Placefinder gave me the correct coordinates back (the same when I entered the correct streetname) and added a quality of 85